# How to know what gets clicked in a DropDownButton

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Per [this page](http://mahapps.com/controls/split_dropdownbutton.html), the DropDownButton is using a ContextMenu to display the ItemsSource. How are we to know what the user clicks on? The Click event on the button isn't for the menu, but the button itself. I see no other events on it.

Comment: Check this events: `DropDownOpened/DropDownClosed`, `ContextMenuOpening/ContextMenuClosing`.

Comment: Don't use events in WPF. Chances are that control has a `SelectedItem` property, -or- that you can assign `Command`s to each item like you would do in a regular `Menu`.

Comment: @HighCore: The DropDownButton is, quote: `This control almost the same as SplitButton with few differences: It has no SelectedItem and SelectedIndex properties and also has no SelectionChanged event.`.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev which means it's not a `Selector`. I wonder why would anyone develop a UI element that's supposed to let you select stuff and not inherit from `Selector`.... S:

Answer (score 15):

I came across this question looking for the same answer. I never really found anything online but discovered this solution on my own. Perhaps it will help someone in the future.

As stated previously the `DropDownButton` uses a `ContextMenu` to display its `ItemsSource`. Basically what I was looking for was a "Menu-like" drop down coming from a button. For example, say you have a `DropDownButton` that says "Add". Maybe you want 2 options like "Add New" and "Add Existing". So this is what I did...

First I made some object to hold the header/content and the command.

```
public class TitledCommand
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

Theoretically you would have a list of these to bind to the `ItemsSource` of the `DropDownButton`.

```
public List<TitledCommand> TitledCommmands { get; private set; }
```

Now we just style the item container for the `DropDownButton` so it picks up the header and command from our objects in the `ItemsSource`.

Include MahApps:

```
xmlns:metroControls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
```

And here is the style...

```
<metroControls:DropDownButton Content="Add" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TitledCommmands}">
    <metroControls:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>        
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
        </Style>          
    </metroControls:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</metroControls:DropDownButton>
```

Comment: In my case using `<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>` was not working, and DisplayMemberPath atribute was better, but you are a lifesaver anyway ;)

Comment: This one should be Accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the item template for the control and can add a handler inside of it like this:

```
<controls:DropDownButton Content="Select me" x:Name="selectMeDropDownButton">
    <controls:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" MouseDown="selectMeDropDownButton_TextBlock_MouseDown" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
</controls:DropDownButton>
```

And implement the event handler in code-behind file like this:

```
void selectMeDropDownButton_TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && this.selectMeDropDownButton.IsExpanded)
    {
        var value = ((TextBlock)e.Source).DataContext;
        // Do something meaningful with the value, it's an item from ItemsSource
    }
}
```

The check for `DropDownButton.IsExpanded` is necessary as the same `ItemTemplate` is applied to the `Content` on the button itself. Of course you can replace TextBlock with any `Control`/`UIElement` you like.

Comment: IMO it's better to use `<MenuItem Click="..." />` instead of `<TextBlock />` in the `<DataTemplate />`.

Comment: I've firstly tried your solution, but the event raises only when you click on the TextBlock itself, not on the full dropdown item row. So if the user is not aware of that (and he shouldn't), he won't understand why his click has no effect some times. Finally I had to implement command solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `attached property` to the ContextMenu/DropDownButton (whichever you prefer). If you did dropdown then get the context menu that it is showing then hook up the `Click` events from it and push the value back to the property.

Answer (score -1):

Use [SplitButton](http://mahapps.com/controls/split_dropdownbutton.html) instead of DropDownButton. The first has SelectionChanged event.